# React Native setState with objects

Tags: react-native, setstate

Let's say I have a functional component called Profile Screen i.e. below:

```
const ProfileScreen = props => {
    const { token, user } = useSelector(state => state.auth);
    const [userData, setUserData] = useState({});

    let userValidatedInfo = validatedUserInfo(user);
    setUserData({...userValidatedInfo});

    return <Text>{userData.fullName}</Text>
}
```

When I go to access one of the properties of the object userData in a `<Text>{userData.fullName}</Text>`i.e. `userData.fullName` it says it is undefined.  What am I doing wrong with my `setState` call (`setUserData`) that it is not updating the current `userData` state

If I console.log userValidatedInfo before the setUserData call, I get the following:

```
Object {
    "fullName": "Person's name",
    //... more properties
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are directly using `userData.fullName` in your Text component. When the component is rendering for the first time before `setUserData` the userData is empty.

So, you can try it like this,

```
{userData.fullName && <Text>{userData.fullName}</Text>}
```

Comment: Attempting to understand the order in which a functional component renders its content.  So it will render what is in the return before my validateUserInfo is called even though that it called before the return JSX ?

Comment: First of all, let me know where you are calling the method `setUserData({...userValidatedInfo});`

Comment: I am calling the `setUserData` function before the `return <Text>{userData.fullName}</Text>` ... added edit above to see exact order

Comment: you should not call setUserData directly. Call it inside useEffect().

Answer (score 1):

I assume `validatedUserInfo` is a normal -sync- function, it must be async. Your code seems fine except `validatedUserInfo`.

See more information about async in javascript [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function).